# Fazer um filtro de negação no ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho um objeto e estou lendo ele no ng-repeat, só que se a chave id for igual a 0777 não quero que seja exibido essa posição,

```
<div ng-repeat="account in accounts | filter:{accountId :'00777'} ">
                {{account.name}} - {{account.accountId}}
</div>
```

estou fazendo o fillter normalmente, exibe somente o objeto, mas tentando usar de forma de negação, não exibe todos as posições do objeto.

```
<div ng-repeat="account in accounts | filter:{accountId :!'00777'} ">
                {{account.name}} - {{account.accountId}}
</div>
```

Se alguém já conseguiu fazer a filtragem com negação dessa forma e puder compartilhar, obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que o filtro seja de negação a `!` precisa estar *dentro* da string passada para o filtro.

Ao invés de:

```
!'00777'
```

Deve ser:

```
'!00777'
```

Caso você tenha uma variável ou função e queira negar o resultado da expressão, é necessário concatenar uma `!` com o item na declaração:

```
filter:{accountId: '!'+algumaFuncao}
```

Um exemplo:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('TesteCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.negateAccountId = function(item) {
        return item.accountId != '00777';
    };
    
    $scope.accounts = 
        [
            {
                name: "Teste 1",
                accountId: '00111'
            },
            {
                name: "Teste 2",
                accountId: '00777'
            },
            {
                name: "Teste 3",
                accountId: '00444'
            },
            
        ]
    ;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TesteCtrl">
       
        <div ng-repeat="account in accounts | filter:{accountId: '!00777'}">
                    {{account.name}} - {{account.accountId}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```